# How can I stop Azure App Service Activity showing each time I open a new solution?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

Sometimes when I open a solution in Visual Studio (2015 Enterprise, Update 1), Azure App Service Activity is loaded as one of the tabs. When I close the tab, it seems to not show it for a little while, then another day upon project open it shows again.

This information isn't relevant to the particular projects as they don't have Azure integration. To me it's simply advertising, which I don't appreciate on a paid edition of VS.

Is there a way I can stop it from showing each time? I've had a look through the options in Visual Studio, but I can't see anything that would control this.

Comment: you can just close it, and next time you open your solution, it will not show up. However, if you publish your web app, it will appear again, and if you don't close it before you close the whole solution, it will appear next time you open your solution. That is what the Visual Studio do, remember what you have got at the latest time your close the solution. I don't understand why this is an issue for you.

Comment: @JackZeng these apps don't integrate Azure at all, so it's irrelevant - I see it as pop-up marketing for Azure, which I don't enjoy.

Comment: @JackZeng I've had to close it lots of times. I don't know what exactly makes it reappear again; VS remembers _for a while_ that I closed it, but eventually I get to see it again.

Comment: @romkyns that's exactly my problem - I close it, it stays down for a while, then it appears again some other time that I open the project. I can understand something like Community Edition having this (free = ads), but it's poor form on the paid versions of VS.

Comment: Ah this could actually be to do with publishing. When I publish, Azure App Service Activity tab shows. So if you publish and then close, that tab will show upon launch. Will keep this in mind to see if it fully explains the appearance of this tab.

Comment: I find this behaviour infuriating - has anybody found a solution, please?

Comment: I don't know if this even exists, but everything in the IDE is scriptable, just about. So if there's an existing VS extension that lets you script stuff, you could script to close the window upon whatever event made sense like solution open or launch. I say this as a suggestion rather than have to write a whole extension. My guess if it exists it would be called IDE / UI tweak or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to control this with this extension:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ed30ceb8-f5f7-4557-9dfc-3f144e5a9989

Supposedly works with 2015. If I try it I'll edit my answer because this is bugging me also.

I have asked the author to add an "auto-apply" feature that would solve your issue supposedly.